# Comparator.reversed() does not compile using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator, method-reference

I have a list with some User objects and i'm trying to sort the list, but only works using method reference, with lambda expression the compiler gives an error:

```
List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(u1, u2, u3);
userList.sort(Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getName())); // works
userList.sort(Comparator.comparing(User::getName).reversed()); // works
userList.sort(Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getName()).reversed()); // Compiler error
```

Error:

```
com\java8\collectionapi\CollectionTest.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            userList.sort(Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getName()).reversed());
                                                     ^
symbol:   method getName()
location: variable u of type Object
1 error
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

This is a weakness in the compiler's type inferencing mechanism. In order to infer the type of `u` in the lambda, the *target type* for the lambda needs to be established. This is accomplished as follows. `userList.sort()` is expecting an argument of type `Comparator<User>`. In the first line, `Comparator.comparing()` needs to return `Comparator<User>`. This implies that `Comparator.comparing()` needs a `Function` that takes a `User` argument. Thus in the lambda on the first line, `u` must be of type `User` and everything works.

In the second and third lines, the target typing is disrupted by the presence of the call to `reversed()`. I'm not entirely sure why; both the receiver and the return type of `reversed()` are `Comparator<T>` so it seems like the target type should be propagated back to the receiver, but it isn't. (Like I said, it's a weakness.)

In the second line, the method reference provides additional type information that fills this gap. This information is absent from the third line, so the compiler infers `u` to be `Object` (the inference fallback of last resort), which fails.

Obviously if you can use a method reference, do that and it'll work. Sometimes you can't use a method reference, e.g., if you want to pass an additional parameter, so you have to use a lambda expression. In that case you'd provide an explicit parameter type in the lambda:

```
userList.sort(Comparator.comparing((User u) -> u.getName()).reversed());
```

It might be possible for the compiler to be enhanced to cover this case in a future release.

Comment: Lambdas are divided into _implicitly-typed_ (no manifest types for parameters) and _explicitly-typed_; method references are divided into _exact_ (no overloads) and _inexact_.  When a generic method call in a receiver position has lambda arguments, and the type parameters cannot be fully inferred from the other arguments, you need to provide either an explicit lambda, an exact method ref, a target type cast, or explicit type witnesses for the generic method call to provide the additional type information needed to proceed.

Comment: @StuartMarks, you are "not entirely sure why" the compiler is acting like this. But what does the _language specification_ say? Should there be sufficient information to determine the generic types, according to the language specification? If so, this is a compiler bug and should be filed and dealt with accordingly. Otherwise it is an area in which the Java language should be improved. Which is it?

Comment: I think we can treat Brian's comments as definitive, as he wrote the specification in question :-)

Comment: Sadly none of this explains why it's working without reversed while it's not working with reversed.

Comment: I was 100% sure this was a problem with the IDE because it didn't make sense that it works without the .reversed() but not with it.

Answer (score 117):

You can work around this limitation by using the two-argument `Comparator.comparing` with `Comparator.reverseOrder()` as the second argument:

```
users.sort(comparing(User::getName, reverseOrder()));
```

Comment: Nice. I like this better than using an explicitly-typed lambda. Or, better yet, `users.sort(reverseOrder(comparing(User::getName)));`.

Comment: Note that the `reverseOrder(Comparator<T>)` method above is in `java.util.Collections`, not in `Comparator`.

Comment: Since question is about problem with *lambda* IMO it would be better to show that proposed solution works for lambdas like `users.sort(comparing(u -> u.getName(), reverseOrder()));` rather than method references (like it was in [first version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25192182/1)).

Answer (score 16):

Contrary to the accepted and upvoted answer for which bounty has been awarded, this doesn't really have anything to do with lambdas.

The following compiles:

```
Comparator<LocalDate> dateComparator = naturalOrder();
Comparator<LocalDate> reverseComparator = dateComparator.reversed();
```

while the following does not:

```
Comparator<LocalDate> reverseComparator = naturalOrder().reversed();
```

This is because the compiler's type inference mechanism isn't strong enough to take two steps at once: determine that the `reversed()` method call needs type parameter `LocalDate` and therefore also the `naturalOrder()` method call will need the same type parameter.

There is a way to call methods and explicitly pass a type parameter.  In simple cases it isn't necessary because it's inferred, but it can be done this way:

```
Comparator<LocalDate> reverseComparator = Comparator.<LocalDate>naturalOrder().reversed();
```

In the example given in the question, this would become:

```
userList.sort(Comparator.comparing<User, String>(u -> u.getName()).reversed());
```

But as shown in the currently accepted answer, anything that helps the compiler inferring type `User` for the `comparing` method call without taking extra steps will work, so in this case you can also specify the type of the lambda parameter explicitly or use a method reference `User::getName` that also includes the type `User`.

Comment: Note that `Comparator.comparing` has two type parameters. For your example, assuming the type of `getName` is `String`, the correct invocation would be:

```userList.sort(Comparator<User, String>.comparing(u -> u.getName()).reversed());```

Comment: @snappieT Thanks, adapted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The static method `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator<T>)` seems to be the most elegant solution that has been proposed. Just one caveat:
`Comparator.reverseOrder()` requires that T implements comparable and relies on the natural sorting order.

`Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator<T>)` has no restriction applied on type `T`