# Java 8 stream "Cannot use this in a static context"

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java8 stream & sorry about the stupid question .  Here is my code which i am trying to create a map of id & value, but i am getting this error, not able to fix. Can anyone help me what is the alternative?

```
    public static Map<Integer, String> findIdMaxValue(){
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> attrIdAttrValueCountMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, String> attrIdMaxValueMap = new HashMap<>(); 
                attrIdAttrValueCountMap.forEach((attrId, attrValueCountMap) -> {
                    attrValueCountMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(this::compareAttrValueCountEntry).findFirst().ifPresent(e -> {
                        attrIdMaxValueMap.put(attrId, e.getKey());
                    });
                });
    }
```

and sorting method

```
public static int compareAttrValueCountEntry(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
    int diff = e1.getValue() - e2.getValue();
    if (diff != 0) {
        return -diff;
    }
    return e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
}
```

I am getting this error

```
"Cannot use this in a static context"
```

Comment: Try to use the actual class name instead of `this`.

Comment: I see, so what is the solution ? I am trying to iterate the map & trying to sort it attrValueCountMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(this::compareAttrValueCountEntry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. While `this::compareAttrValueCountEntry` would be easy to
fix by changing it to `ContainingClassName::compareAttrValueCountEntry`, this method is unnecessary
as there are several factory methods like `Map.Entry.comparingByKey`, `Map.Entry.comparingByValue`,
`Comparator.reversed` and `Comparator.thenComparing`, which can be combined to achieve the same goal

This guards you from the errors made within `compareAttrValueCountEntry`. It’s tempting to compare `int`
values by subtracting, but this is error prone as the difference between two `int` values doesn’t always
fit into the `int` range, so overflows can occur. Also, negating the result for reversing the order is
broken, as the value might be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which has no positive counterpart, hence, negating it
will overflow back to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead of changing the sign.

Instead of looping via `forEach` to add to another map, you may use a cleaner stream operation producing
the map and you can simplify `sorted(…).findFirst()` to `min(…)` which in not only shorter, but a
potentially cheaper operation.

Putting it together, we get

```
Map<Integer, String> attrIdMaxValueMap =
    attrIdAttrValueCountMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .min(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
                        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())).get().getKey()));
```

Note that I prepended a `filter` operation rejecting empty maps, which ensures that there will always be
a matching element, so there is no need to deal with `ifPresent` or such alike. Instead, `Optional.get`
can be called unconditionally.

Since this method is called `findIdMaxValue`, there might be a desire to reflect that by calling `max`
on the Stream instead of `min`, wich is only a matter of which comparator to reverse:

```
Map<Integer, String> attrIdMaxValueMap =
    attrIdAttrValueCountMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .max(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
                       .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
                .get().getKey()));
```

Unfortunately, such constructs hit the limitations of the type inference, which requires us to either,
use nested constructs (like `Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder())` instead of
`Map.Entry.comparingByKey().reversed()`) or to insert explicit types, like with
`Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()`. In the second variant, reversing the second comparator,
we are hitting the litimation twice…

In this specific case, there might be a point in creating the comparator only once, keeping it in a variable and reuse it within the stream operation:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> valueOrMinKey
    = Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
         .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder()));

Map<Integer, String> attrIdMaxValueMap =
    attrIdAttrValueCountMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().max(valueOrMinKey).get().getKey()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the method `compareAttrValueCountEntry` is declared static,

replace the method reference

`this::compareAttrValueCountEntry`

with

`<Yourclass>::compareAttrValueCountEntry`

Comment: I found a better approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567575/sort-map-by-value-using-java-8