# How to sort an array of key values alphabetically by the value in a stream? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I'm trying to learn more about comparators and streams and I was wondering the best solution to sort an array of objects with key values, sorting alphabetically by the value. Any help is hugely appreciated!

```
Example Array:
[
   {key: "93743743", value: "Mary Smith"},
   {key: "6624c357", value: "Tom Spitz"},
   {key: "03453459", value: "John Doe"},
   {key: "24623145", value: "Ernie Ball"}
]

Expected Result:
[
   {key: "24623145", value: "Ernie Ball"}
   {key: "03453459", value: "John Doe"},
   {key: "93743743", value: "Mary Smith"},
   {key: "6624c357", value: "Tom Spitz"},

]
```

Having a bit of trouble with the exact syntax using it in a stream (using a stream to subsequently filter and return an array of the names). Could also filter the array after if easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567575/sort-map-by-value-using-lambdas-and-streams  Or, similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+sort+map+value+streams

Answer (score 0):

With an array of `MyObject` defined as follows:

```java
record MyObject(String key, String value) {}
```

You can use `Comparator.comparing` with a method reference to sort it.

```java
MyObject[] res = Arrays.stream(arr)
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::value)).toArray(MyObject[]::new);
// or your getter may be named as MyObject::getValue
```

Comment: See a working example [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZHNTsMwDMfFcXsKq6cGjQjWbmOdOPB1QZo4lBvikHXZltE2leMWlalPwmUHeCUOPA3J1glNRJZiOT__7dgfn2tRie32q6TF2eXPybfKCo0ELspLUik_nXSLcpaqBJJUGANToXLYdDtt0JAge1VazSGzT35MqPLl8wsIXBrmyA7KROMcpvXjbC0TahF4lXUPWr8SaSkt3Vj8wO00EK5gk8u3v2xvHIxCZ14PvKnAGuJM0cpjPTjmhsN-mASDkeOedAZxoejdYbaGPcfweRAOrI0d_KBXOdxp-V-yHw77wUU4cNQ95krCjUhTjzWT475RGtv3NaKoDTeEUmS-_Qvjxg5Xzv1bnRUCBWnkyc61M_AP-VG0nwbjpHcS_p9yFNmGmKu20Ah-JRA0RK4eg7g2JDOuS-KFFaQ097VDm26zX2-75cO2fwE).