# Type inference broken with fluent API

Tags: java, lambda, type-inference

I try to write following code:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
// ... populate the map
m.entrySet().stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey()).reversed())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This does not compile, because the inferred type for `e` is `Object`. However, if I remove the `.reversed()` call, the inference works. I have to spell out the type for `e`, which is ugly:

```
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, String> e) -> e.getKey()).reversed())
```

Compiler can infer the type for `Comparator.comparing`, but when I add `reversed()`, it cannot. Why?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173599/829571) explains why it doesn't compile.

You have several ways to fix the code:

```
//cheat a bit
.sorted(Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder()))

//provide the target type
.sorted(Entry.<String, String> comparingByKey().reversed())

//explicitly give the type of e
.sorted(Comparator.comparing((Entry<String, String> e) -> e.getKey()).reversed())
```

Comment: This are two alternative solutions. But neither is as elegant as the intuitive original one. Actually, I'm designing an API, that suffers from the same problem as the `sorted()` method. I wonder, if I can change something in the API to make the simple version work.

Comment: @Oliv I don't think these are less elegant, just different - however I agree with you that actual answer would need to explain why your solution doesn't work

Comment: I mean, less elegant than `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey()).reversed())` or even `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey).reversed())`

Comment: Neither do they allow further chaining, such as with `.thenComparing(...)`

Comment: @Oliv I've added more information. Note that if you want to use `thenComparing()` you will need to use the same tricks in the second comparator.

Comment: @assylias, thanks for the reference to answer. It really is a compiler misfeature.

Comment: `.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey())))` or 
`.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))` will work too

Answer (score 0):

The static method you are using here

```
Comparator.comparing()
```

is a generic method, but you do not specify here, what it takes as an argument, and what it returns - it needs to be specified somewhere.

My suggestion is a small change, replacing casting `e` to `Map.Entry`, that could potentially look better

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
// ... populate the map
m.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>comparing(Map.Entry::getKey).reversed())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Normally, Java infers the type arguments. But after adding `reverser()`, I need to spell them explicitly. Why?

Comment: I made some tests and when you have code without `reversed()`, the `Map.Entry::getKey` is resolved as `(stringStringEntry) -> stringStringEntry.getKey()`, but in case when you have it reversed, the same `Map.Entry::getKey` is resolved as `(Function<Object, U>) (t) -> Map.Entry.getKey(t)` which is clearly wrong, as now we would have `Comparator<Object>` returned as well as undefined type `U` and wrong `getKey` method call as it takes `t` as a parameter and is called on `Map.Entry` class. Very interesting, but still not understandable for me.