# Why can chained comparators with lambdas not infer generic type

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
public class Car {

    private float enginePower;
    private float wheelDiameter;

    public float getEnginePower() {
        return enginePower;
    }

    static final Comparator<Car> simpleCarComparator = Comparator.comparing(c -> c.enginePower);

    static final Comparator<Car> advancedCarComparator = simpleCarComparator.thenComparing(c -> c.wheelDiameter);

    // Does not work
    static final Comparator<Car> bothInOneCarComparator = Comparator.comparing(c -> c.enginePower).thenComparing(c -> c.wheelDiameter);
}
```

The last Comparator does not compile, because the Compiler thinks the lambdas are  `Function<Object,?>` leaving `c` without an `enginePower` member. I know I can easily fix this, by either casting `(Car c) -> c.enginePower` or using a method reference `Car::getEnginePower`, then the compiler can infer the type for both lambdas.

However I would like to understand why the compiler cannot simply infer the type and figure out by itself that `c` is a `Car`. While `c` could be any superclass of `Car` to make the assignment legal, only `Car` itself makes sense here and for the `simpleCarComparator` the Compiler also infered that `c` is a `Car` and not just `Object`.

Comment: You can also fix the last line with `Comparator.<Car> comparing(...)`.

Comment: Related [Comparator.reversed() does not compile using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/comparator-reversed-does-not-compile-using-lambda)

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks, obviously looked for the wrong keywords when I googled this questions

Comment: @assylias That would have to be `Comparator.<Car,Float>comparing(...)`

Comment: @MaxBenson Yes indeed.