# Why does using a base class for a method reference cause a compiler error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-stream, comparator

I'm using `Comparator`s to sort streams and I've come across a compiler error that I don't understand.

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Base {
    private LocalDate date;
    public LocalDate getDate() { return date; }
    ...
}
class Sub extends Base { ... }
```

I'm creating two comparators to sort `Sub`s by their date, one by the natural order and one in the reverse order. The following code compiles:

```
Comparator<Sub> fwd = Comparator.comparing(Sub::getStartDate);
Comparator<Sub> rev1 = Comparator.comparing(Sub::getStartDate).reversed();
Comparator<Sub> rev2 = fwd.reversed();
```

Realising that `getDate()` is defined on `Base`, I thought I'd try the following:

```
Comparator<Sub> fwd = Comparator.comparing(Base::getStartDate);
Comparator<Sub> rev1 = Comparator.comparing(Base::getStartDate).reversed();  // Compiler error
Comparator<Sub> rev2 = fwd.reversed();  // OK
```

Surprisingly (to me), the code for `rev2` compiles okay, while the code for `rev1` produces the following errors:

```
Cannot infer type argument(s) for <T, U> comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U>)
The type Base does not define getStartDate(Object) that is applicable here
```

Why do I get these compiler errors? And why can I effectively circumvent them when building `rev2` from `fwd`?

(I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3) and Java v1.8.0_162 if that's relevant.)

Comment: You probably just need to explicitly state the generic type argument on the `comparing` method.

Comment: @aominè I'm not convinced this is a duplicate of the question you refer to. In that question there is no parent/child class relationship. Further, in that question, using a method reference compiles, while in mine it does not. Can you explain why you think the other question's answer explains my situation.

Comment: @dave post reopened.

Comment: Where is the class `Competition` in your explanation?

Comment: @YassinHajaj The reference to `Competition` was a mistake and came from my actual problem as opposed to the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in my question. I've edited my question to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated it this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/comparator-reversed-does-not-compile-using-lambda#answer-25173599), the target typing is disrupted by the presence of the call to `reversed()`:

```
Comparator<Sub> rev1 =
    Comparator.comparing(Base::getStartDate)
              .reversed(); // Compiler error - incompatible types
```

It seems like in this situation compiler infers the following type arguments:

```
Comparator<Sub> rev1 =
    Comparator.<Base, LocalDate>comparing(Base::getStartDate)
              .reversed(); // Compiler error - incompatible types
```

To get rid of the error, you can provide type arguments explicitly:

```
Comparator<Sub> rev1 =
    Comparator.<Sub, LocalDate>comparing(Base::getStartDate)
              .reversed(); // Okay, no problem
```

Or use two-argument [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Comparator<Sub> rev1 =
    Comparator.comparing(Base::getStartDate, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tested your first solution and it resolved the error which suggests your supposition re type inference is correct. I had discovered your second solution already and have retained it as it seems clearer (and easier on the eye).