# How to sort by key in hashmap of objects without overriding compareTo?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have this HashMap `Map<Person, List<Information>>`. How can I sort this map in reversed order by the double attribute in class `Person`?

I tried this:

```
origin.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(k -> k.getKey().getScore())
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

It works, but since I use the function `.reversed` at the end of `getScore()` then `getKey()` returns error. `Cannot resolve method 'getKey' in 'Object`

Class Person:

```
public class Person{
double score;
Information information;

}
```

Comment: Refer this thread https://www.java67.com/2017/07/how-to-sort-map-by-values-in-java-8.html

Comment: See this related post [comparator-reversed-does-not-compile-using-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/comparator-reversed-does-not-compile-using-lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to work around that issue is to move the Comparator outside of your stream pipeline:

```
Comparator<Entry<Person,List<Information>>> byScore = Comparator.comparingDouble(k -> k.getKey().getScore());
    origin.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(byScore.reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

or provide an explicit parameter type in the lambda:

```
origin.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((Comparator.comparingDouble((Entry<Person,List<Information>> k) -> k.getKey().getScore())).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: both of them does not work, the first one returns `Cannot resolve symbol 'byScore'` and the second : Type 'ap.parser.ApInput.Absyn.Entry' does not have type parameters

Comment: You need to import `import java.util.Map.Entry;`